# Como abrir link em uma parte específica de uma nova guia

Tags: html, css

Quero que, quando a pessoa clicar em um link, abra uma nova guia em uma parte específica da nova guia.

Comment: Cara se vc tem uma pergunta nova, abra outra pergunta. Qual sua intenção em editar o conteúdo de uma pergunta que já foi respondida e fechada e ainda por cima era sobre outra coisa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para abrir a página em uma nova guia, adicione a propriedade `target=_blank`.
Se quiser que ela seja aberta em uma parte específica, coloque o id correspondente a este elemento no link, assim:

```
<a href="novapagina.html#footer" target="_blank">Abrir nova página</a>
```

Neste exemplo, a nova página abre imediatamente no elemento com o id `footer`.

Comment: Obrigado, não estava dando certo porque eu estava colocando uma / no href
("novapagina.html/#footer")